# Load a JSON file into a JS object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, file

I try to load a json file into a JavaScript var but it just doesn't work out.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify('./test.json');
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(obj.details.ProductID);
```

it says that it can't read property ProductID of undefined.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: load your file seperately, take it into a variable, and then stringify it?

Comment: @Satej S That would give me a string, not an object ?

Comment: Where have you read that `JSON.stringify` loads a file?

Comment: @Vohuman think I misred it

Comment: Can you add the JSON you are trying to read to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an AJAX call to get the file. `$.getJSON` was intended for exactly this purpose:

```
$.getJSON('./test.json', function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.details.ProductID);
});
```

Comment: What should I do if I want json file to set among js tags on HTML between <script></script> tags?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "/test.json", function( obj ) {
  console.log(obj.details.ProductID);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify()` first argument needs to be a valid JSON string, not a file.

You need to use AJAX to retrieve file from server:

```
$.getJSON('./test.json', function(responseObject){
    var obj = responseObject
    console.log(obj)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, just use this:

```
const dataObjectFromFile = require('./path/to/datafile.json');
```