# how to get google heat map LatLng with JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, heatmap

I want get **google heat map LatLng** with **Json** file

This is my google heat map function

```
 function initMap() {

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 11,
            center: {lat: 37.782551, lng: -122.445368}
        });

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: getPoints(),
            map: map
        });

    }
```

This is my LatLng function , i want instead use getPoints() function JSON file

```
function getPoints() {
        return [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437150/load-a-json-file-into-a-js-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you make a file called points.json that looks like this and is available in the same directory as the HTML for your web page.

```
{
  "points": [
    [37.782551, -122.445368],
    [37.782745, -122.444586],
    [37.782842, -122.443688],
    [37.782919, -122.442815],
    [37.782992, -122.442112]
  ]
}
```

Then you need to request the JSON file from the webserver. If you can use recent web browsers, you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for this:

```
function requestPoints() {
  fetch('points.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(initMap);
}
```

If you can't use recent web browsers, then you can do something similar with [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

When the network request for 'points.json' comes back, this will call initMap with the JSON. Then you can use the JSON like this:

```
function initMap(json) {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 37.782551, lng: -122.445368}
  });

  var points = json.points;
  var data = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    data[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i][0], points[i][1]);
  }

  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: data,
    map: map
  });

}
```

If you are following the Google examples, you'll want to change the callback parameter in the script request from `callback=initMap` to `callback=requestPoints`.